# MySQL - How can I make my query conditional based on the number of rows it would return?

Tags: mysql, select, union, rows

I've seen similar posts regarding this kind of thing but I'd like personal help with my query.

What we have is a media site that, when a media item is selected, displays three related media items in a sidebar. The items should display two items with a later date and one with an earlier date than the currently chosen one. If there are not two with a later date, show just one with a later date and two with an earlier date. If the currently chosen media is already the most recent (having no related media with a later date), then just show the three with earlier dates. Of course, these three results need to be the three closest in date to the currently selected media.

I have a query that works almost perfectly:

```
    $query = "
    (SELECT
        media.*, 
        media_series.series_name, 
        media_books.book_name, 
        media_books.book_shortname  
    FROM media 
    LEFT JOIN media_series ON media.series = media_series.id
    LEFT JOIN media_books ON media.book = media_books.id 
    WHERE media.date >= '$media_date' AND media.series = '$series_id'
    AND media.id <> '$media_id_2'
    ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(media.date, '$media_date')) LIMIT 2)
    UNION
    (SELECT
        media.*, 
        media_series.series_name, 
        media_books.book_name, 
        media_books.book_shortname 
    FROM media 
    LEFT JOIN media_series ON media.series = media_series.id
    LEFT JOIN media_books ON media.book = media_books.id 
    WHERE media.date <= '$media_date' AND media.series = '$series_id'
    AND media.id <> '$media_id_2'
    ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(media.date, '$media_date'))) 
    ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 3
    ";
```

The first `SELECT` gets up to two items having a later date, then, using `UNION`, the second `SELECT` gets any items having an earlier date.  Finally, the `LIMIT 3` at the end makes sure we only get three rows overall.

The only flaw with this query that I can see is that if the currently chosen media is the OLDEST (meaning it has no related media with earlier dates), then only two results will display, because the first `SELECT` limits to 2 and the second `SELECT` returns nothing.

I need the first `SELECT` to return 3 rows only if the second `SELECT` returns zero rows.  I was thinking I could use `CASE` somehow, but I'm not sure how exactly.  Can you help?

Note: As a temporary solution, I'm currently running the query, then checking the number of returned rows with PHP, and if it's less than 3 I run the whole query over again but with `LIMIT 3` in the first `SELECT`. This works, but I'd like to avoid running the two queries if possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$query = "
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT * FROM
 (SELECT
     media.*, 
     media_series.series_name, 
     media_books.book_name, 
     media_books.book_shortname,
     @rn := @rn + 2 rn
  FROM (SELECT @rn :=-1 ) r
  CROSS JOIN media 
  LEFT JOIN media_series ON media.series = media_series.id
  LEFT JOIN media_books ON media.book = media_books.id 
  WHERE media.date >= '$media_date' AND media.series = '$series_id'
  AND media.id <> '$media_id_2'
  ORDER BY media.date LIMIT 3) sq1
 UNION ALL
 (SELECT
     media.*, 
     media_series.series_name, 
     media_books.book_name, 
     media_books.book_shortname,
     @rn := @rn + 2 rn
  FROM (SELECT @rn :=0 ) r
  CROSS JOIN media 
  LEFT JOIN media_series ON media.series = media_series.id
  LEFT JOIN media_books ON media.book = media_books.id 
  WHERE media.date < '$media_date' AND media.series = '$series_id'
  AND media.id <> '$media_id_2'
  ORDER BY media.date DESC LIMIT 3) sq2
 ORDER BY rn LIMIT 3) mq
ORDER BY date DESC
";
```

(The first `SELECT * FROM` may not be necessary - it would be if running this query directly through SQL, but the equivalent line in your code is not present, so it might be automatically generated elsewhere.)

Proof of concept [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f7745/4).

Comment: Wow, that's pretty complicated compared to what I'm used to.  I've never seen `CROSS JOIN` or some of the other syntax you're using.  I'll give this a try later on and see how it goes.  In the meantime, my "temporary PHP solution" should be okay.  I realized that running the multiple queries isn't a huge deal since it will only have to happen on rare occasions.  I still wanted to know how to do this, though, so thank you very much!!